# Can someone assist with translating this Object Oriented Design diagram example into code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am going through Sandi Metz's Practical Object Oriented Design. In Chapter 4, Creating Flexible Interfaces, I am presented with some UML diagrams to show the interactions and messages of two classes. For example, below is the following diagram from the book:

[image]

The description of this image is the following:

> Therefore, this sequence diagram can be read as follows: Customer Moe sends the suitable_trips message to the Trip class, which is activated to process it and then, when finished, returns a response.

Would an implementation like the following be accurate?

```
class Customer
  attr_reader :name, :on_date, :of_difficulty, :need_bike
  def initialize(name, on_date, of_difficulty, need_bike)
    @name = name
    @on_date = on_date
    @of_difficulty = of_difficulty
    @need_bike = need_bike
  end
end

class Trip
  attr_reader :trip
  def initialize(trip)
    @trip = trip
  end

  def suitable_trips(on_date, of_difficulty, need_bike)
    #gives list of suitable trips based on factors
  end
end


moe = Customer.new("moe", "now", "easy", "yes")
trip = Trip.new('Grand Canyon')

trip.suitable_trips(moe.on_date, moe.of_difficulty, moe.need_bike)
```

Sometimes I think I get it but then I'll run into another UML diagram and then get confused by wording especially when it comes to receiver and sender. I just want to be sure I'm getting this right so I understand completely where methods are supposed to go and in which class.

Comment: That diagram says that "on_date, of_difficulty, needs_bike" need to be arguments to `suitable_trips`, not attributes of a customer.

Comment: I made an edit to reflect that thanks. Would this still be an accurate representation?

Comment: Nope, still off. The diagram (and the accompanying text) says that the _customer_ should send that message (and in your case it's some higher-level unnamed entity). I don't remember details of this particular book, but if you scroll a bit further, good chances are you'll find the correct implementation of this. :)

Comment: Also pay closer attention to the actors in the diagram. It's "customer Moe" (concrete instance), but "class Trip" (not a concrete trip)

Comment: Unfortunately its all shown in more UML diagrams and not coded out but I'll just keep trying

Comment: yeah, keep at it, the reward is worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Therefore, this sequence diagram can be read as follows: `Customer` Moe sends the `suitable_trips` message to the `Trip` class, which is activated to process it and then, when finished, returns a response.

Let’s implement it exactly as stated.

```
class Trip
  class << self # class methods
    def suitable_trips(on_date, of_difficulty, need_bike)
      # gives list of suitable trips based on factors
      [Trip.new(...), Trip.new(...), ...]
    end
  end
end

class Customer
  attr_reader :name
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end
  # this is a search function, specific for Moe
  def best_fit(on_date, of_difficulty, need_bike)
    trips = Trip.suitable_trips(on_date, of_difficulty, need_bike)
    # get the best accordingly to some rules
    #   that are specific for Moe
    trips.find { |trip| ... }
  end
end
```

And use it like:

```
moe = Customer.new("Moe")
moe.best_fit("2019-06-01", :hard, false)
#⇒ Trip instance or `nil`
```

---

*Sidenote:* there are tons of great books on Ruby and my *personal* advice would be to pick up one of them instead. Sandi Metz is probably a great populist, but it makes sense to read tutorials from people who are actually good at *coding*.

Comment: that book is not about ruby, though :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev well, whatever :)